# Periodic Script- Daemon-

Tags: unix, shell, daemon, init, hp-ux

ux and i need delete a specific file every day.
then I need to do a shell script or something else with a simple command for example

```
# rm <filename>
```

But i need add this script to init, or convert this script in daemon TO GRANT that every day at 20:00, this script run and delete the file.

I guess that the above is the procedure, but I can be wrong.  Can you please guide me in this situation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set up a [cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/hp-ux-unix-cron-job-configuration-tutorial/).

Comment: thanks for info and guide. Tomorrow, I will see this command.

Another question.. This crontab run after I restart the server for example or I close the session, or I need consider other things..?

Comment: yes, cron daemon runs at startup, unless you specifically disable it

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `man crontab`.

The crontab line you are looking for will look like this:

```
0 20 * * * rm <filename>
```

You would put this line as an entry in the crontab of the user it needs to run as (e.g. root).